# Replace NULL Value with 0 when crossing measures in Browser SSAS MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I want to replace Null values when browsing in the cube, when i do IIF or coalesce I get null values for years that doesn't have Data (all dimension rows), I just want to replace null for current data crossed. Here is an exemple to explain more :

```
Year   Measure 1     Measure 2
2015     55            60
2016     44            70
2017      30           (null)
```

Problem behaviour when I use ISEMPTY OR COALESCE

`Year         Measure 1      Measure 2
(All TimeDim years) 0               0
    2012            0               0
    2013            0               0
    2014             0              0
    2015            55              60
    2016            44              70
    2017            30              0`

The dataset is bigger now with useless values.

What I want :

`Year   Measure 1     Measure 2
    2015     55            60
    2016     44            70
    2017      30           0`

How to solve this ? thank you.

Comment: isnull(field, yourdefaultvalue)

Comment: @GuidoG Same problem, i will get all dimension rows with null replaced with 0 + ISNULL is not Available in MDX

Comment: Post the query...

Comment: so how does isnull not help you ? If you want help, than help us help you and post sample data and expected outcome, not images but text. Also post your query

Comment: how do you get from 3 records in your first table to 7 records ? are you joining tables or what are you doing here

Comment: It seems to me that your problem has not much to do with null. Do you want all records from your table where Measure_1 is different from 0 and different from null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an emxample people can play with:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[Australia];
```

Results in:

[image]

This is the simple amendment that causes the expansion of the rows:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount NEW] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] = 0
     ,0
     ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount NEW]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[Australia];
```

Results in

[image]

So we could just amend the NEW measure a bit more to this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount NEW] AS 
    IIF
    (
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] = 0
      AND 
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] <> 0
     ,0
     ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount NEW]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[Australia];
```

Then we have:

[image]

BE AWARE ... getting rid of nulls within the cube space can seriously degrade the performance of your mdx scripts so use the above with care - better still don't bother with the above and in your client to the mdx do the transformation of (null) => 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `IS` operator with the `NULL` reference. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/is-mdx)

Another option would be to wrap it in an `IIF` statement. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/iif-mdx)